# showing information of referenced schemas using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I have 2 schemas as follows:

In Product, I have an array of Elements separated by comma (,)

The Element Schema defines each element inside the Elements field in Product

```
var Product = new Schema({

            name: {type: String},
            Elements: {type : String}
});

var Element= new Schema({

            title: {type: String},
            code : {type : String}
});
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="productController as product">
    <div ng-repeat="pro in product.product.Elements.split(', ')" ng-init="getCategory(pro)">
        <h3>{{pro}} {{data.code}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

In productController

```
productid = $routeParams.id;
var getthatProduct = function(){
    productFactory.getthatProduct(productid, function(data){
        console.log('[CONTROLLER] That Product:',data);
        that.product = data;

    })
}
getthatProduct();

$scope.getCategory = function(data){

elementFactory.getElements(data, function(data){
        console.log('[CONTROLLER] That Element:',data);
        $scope.data = data;

    })
}
```

elementFactory:

```
  factory.getElements= function(data, callback){
    $http({
        url:'api/seeelements',
        method:'GET',
        params:{title: data}
    }).then(function(response){
        //console.log(data);
        callback(response.data)
    })
}
```

getElements is defined in my factory which fetch all the elements info from Element Schema

I can fetch {pro} but i'm not able to fetch the element info.

How to display the Element.title for each element in a single product ?

Comment: Show code for getElements. Also you are going to overwrite `$scope.data` every iteration of `ng-repeat`. Are you seeing correct ingredient in console log?

Comment: @charlietfl see the edited question

Comment: @charlietfl i am seeing all elements in console

Comment: Ok...so main issue I see now is you are going to overwrite $scope.data every time. Also shouldn't use `ng-init` for this and should just iterate product.product.Elements as proper array in controller and make controller do all the requsts without using ng-init

Comment: @charlietfl can you please provide code, since i am very new to this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation, don't use ng-init.
Get elements, create a hash and use it then.

```
productid = $routeParams.id;
$scope.elementsHash={};
$scope.productElements = [];
var getthatProduct = function(){
    productFactory.getthatProduct(productid, function(data){
        console.log('[CONTROLLER] That Product:',data);
        that.product = data;
        $scope.productElements = that.product.product.Elements.split(', ');
        $scope.productElements.forEach(function(elem){
            $scope.getCategory(elem); //get each element's info
        }); 
    })
}
getthatProduct();

$scope.getCategory = function(data){

elementFactory.getElements(data, function(resp){
        console.log('[CONTROLLER] That Element:',resp);
        $scope.elementsHash[data] = resp; //this will update the hashes e.g {'sometitle':{title:'sometitle',code:123}}
    })
}
```

now in your html, use that hash

```
<div class="productController as product">
    <div ng-repeat="pro in productElements">
        <h3>Element title: {{pro}}</h3>
        <p>{{elementsHash[pro].code}}</p> <!-- e.g. elementsHash.sometitle.code
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps